# scp to EC2 Permission denied (publickey) but ssh works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can `ssh` to my ubuntu AWS EC2 instance but can't do `scp` to file transfer

I am using below command at my mac

```
sudo scp - i file.pem /Users/me/proposal.pdf ubuntu@ec2-IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/mnt/projectFolder/
```

And I am seeing error `ubuntu@ec2-IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com Permission denied (publickey) Lost connection`

**What I have tried:**

1. Followed this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/531589/cannot-scp-file-to-an-ec2-instance-that-i-can-ssh-to) and tried Beau's answer
2. Made sure my .pem file has 400 permission
3. Made sure my `authorized_keys` file in `.sshd` folder has my `.pem` file as authorized

What am I missing?

Comment: what are the file permissions on "/mnt/projectFolder"? Who are the owner and group? Make sure that ubuntu is either the owner, part of the group, or the directory has write permissions for "other".

Comment: @JohnHanley I just did chmod 777 for that forlder so everyone has read/write/execute access but I still get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo in your command. The command should be (note the `-i`):

`sudo scp -i file.pem /Users/me/proposal.pdf ubuntu@ec2-IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/mnt/projectFolder/`

Comment: OMG you saved me! I should look carefully more

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was caused by the EC2 instance having no read/execute permissions to `/usr/bin/scp`.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/scp
---------- 1 root root 133720 Nov 23 07:38 /usr/bin/scp
```

Issue was solved by running `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/scp`

I know this was not the problem that OP had but future searches may bring up this question and help someone else.